# Why does sympy.solve produce empty array for certain inequalities

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, inequality

sympy's solve seems to generally work for inequalities. For example:

```
from sympy import symbols, solve;

x = symbols('x');

print(solve('x^2 > 4', x)); # ((-oo < x) & (x < -2)) | ((2 < x) & (x < oo))
```

In some cases where all values of x or no values of x are valid solutions, `solve()` returns `True` or `False` to indicate that.

```
print(solve('x^2 > 4 + x^2', x)); # False
print(solve('x^2 >= x^2', x)); # True
```

However, there are other cases where I would expect a result of True or False and instead I get `[]`:

```
print(solve('x - x > 0', x)); # []
print(solve('x - x >= 0', x)); # []
```

Why does this happen/what am I doing wrong?

Comment: it seems when one side is `0` then `bool` otherwise `[] | bool`

Comment: same issue with `solve(StrictGreaterThan(x , x)); # False ` and `solve(StrictGreaterThan(x - x , 0); # []`

Comment: Solve is not really designed for inequalities. Use something else like `reduce_inequalities`.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that expressions are not WYSIWYG: your expressions did not have `x` in them:

```
print(solve('x - x > 0', x)); # []  <-- solve(0>0, x) => solve(False, x)
print(solve('x - x >= 0', x)); # []  <-- solve(0>=0, x) => solve(True, x)
```

Since `x` does not appear in either expression, there are no values of `x` to report in the first case that can make the False become True; in the second case there is no way to represent the Universal set (since any value of x cannot change the value of True to anything else). So in both cases there is no solution to report (though maybe an error or at least `x<=oo` could be reported for the second case) but in general: if the requested symbol does not appear in the equation (at the outset or after simplification) then `[]` is returned (and `x` does not appear in True).